# Benchmark Amazon Redshift JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT

Tags: postgresql, statistics, benchmarking, amazon-redshift

Can any one help me with benchmarking/performance stats for redshift JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT
function?

Should we use this function for huge amount of data for extracting json data(Around 50 million)?

Comment: Huh, so Amazon have ported PostgreSQL's json functions over to Reshift (or rather, ParAccel). Hard to say how well they perform... I think you're likely to just have to benchmark it yourself.

Comment: @CraigRinger you can check details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html                                                           Also JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH
JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT are supported in redshift.

Answer (score 2):

50 million is peanuts for redshift, but extract json stuff is certainly slower than anything in a regular column.

On a 24xdc1.large cluster

2.3B rows

```
select count(*) from table where json_extract_path_text(what_extra_json, 'is_logged_in') is not null;
```

### count

1364239102
(1 row)

in 24sec